Finding neighboring cells using Gmsh API
I am creating a simple mesh on a square domain, $[-5,5]\times[-5,5]$ using the following .geo file
lc = 1e-12;

Point(1) = {-5, -5, 0, lc};
Point(2) = {5, -5, 0, lc};
Point(3) = {5, 5, 0, lc};
Point(4) = {-5, 5, 0, lc};

Line(1) = {1, 2};
Line(2) = {2, 3};
Line(3) = {3, 4};
Line(4) = {4, 1};

Curve Loop(1) = {1, 2, 3, 4};
Plane Surface(1) = {1};
Physical Surface("Boundary") = {1};


// Meshing options
Mesh.Algorithm = 5;
//Mesh.Voronoi =1;
Mesh.CharacteristicLengthMin = 1.5; // Minimum grid size
Mesh.CharacteristicLengthMax = 2;  // Maximum grid size


// Generate 2D mesh
Mesh 2;

Then I am accesing the mesh in Julia using the api, as
gmsh.initialize()
gmsh.open("path/to/mesh.msh")
global entities = gmsh.model.getEntities()
global nodeTags, nodeCoords, nodeParams = gmsh.model.mesh.getNodes(-1, -1)
global elemTypes, elemTags, elemNodeTags = gmsh.model.mesh.getElements(-1, -1)

Since I am doing FVM, I need the neighbours of each cell, to compute fluxes but I can't find how I can access that information. I think x7.jl and neighbors.py does this, but I am not able to discern how.

Seems like this is a feature that people have been asking about for a long time. Here is a thread from the Gmsh mailing list with some Python pseudocode and discussion https://onelab.info/pipermail/gmsh/2019/012963.html

I would be happy even if I can modify that example to my needs. I am just not able to comprehend the data structure fully, hence unable to proceed.
